# jQuery & Bootstrap not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently started using/learning bootstrap and jQuery for my site and while I was searching for ideas. I went across bootstrap dialogs which I thought could help me make my site more modernized. While I was testing code snippets it in the site. There seemed to be no response from jquery at all.

```
<li id="Login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
```

This `li` tag above is being printed out by `php`. The code below is placed in the `body` tags

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Login").click(function(){
        BootstrapDialog.show({
        message: 'Hi Apple!'
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

code samples are very much appreciated if there was an error because I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that i got the snippets from http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/#available-options

Comment: do you get any errors in console? make sure you have `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` inside `js/` directory

Comment: I got snippets from w3schools and they seemed to work fine for me and those files are correctly placed in their respective directories

Comment: Check error in browser console

Comment: I have searched on how to check jquery errors and i seemed to have gotten one error which is "Uncaught ReferenceError: BootstrapDialog is not defined".. How to fix this error?

Comment: can you show you own libraries? maybe need to fix how you call you libraries...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not included **bootstrap-dialog.js.**

I tried running your code into jsfiddle and it gave me `ReferenceError: BootstrapDialog is not defined`

you can find `bootstrap-dialog-js` on nakupanda's github account : https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/tree/master/src/js

Comment: @DeathKing If your problem is solved, you can accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like this and show me the result

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Login").on('click', function(event){
    BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: 'Hi Apple!'
    });
});
});

</script>
```